# How do I get rid of the following sign-conversion warning?

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, unsigned

I am getting the following warning whenever the function initSetArray() is called :

```
error: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Werror=sign-conversion]
  setarray = (set*)malloc(sizeof(set) * number_of_sets);
```

The function initSetArray simply initializes the setarray.

```
void initSetArray(set *setarray, int number_of_sets, int number_of_blocks)
{
    setarray = (set*)malloc(sizeof(set) * number_of_sets);
}
```

I have defined two structures which are used in the helper function defined above:

```
typedef struct{
    uint64_t tag;   // For identifying the block
    uint8_t valid;  // Valid bit for the block
    uint8_t dirty;  // Dirty bit for the block
} block;

typedef struct{
    uint64_t index; // For identifying the set
    block* way;
} set;
```

I cannot exactly find out which variable is of type "long unsigned int". What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not your question, but if you would like the caller to see the allocated `setarray` you will need to pass `set**` instead of `set*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement

```
setarray = (set*)malloc(sizeof(set) * number_of_sets);
```

the variable `number_of_sets` is an integer (int), and because it is used in an expression with `sizeof` (size_t), the value is converted to match.

`size_t` is usually an `unsigned long`.  If you don't like the warning, this would fix it:

```
setarray = (set*)malloc(sizeof(set) * (size_t) number_of_sets);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `malloc` function takes a `size_t` argument, and `size_t` is defined for your build as `unsigned long int` (as it frequently is). In your call:

```c
setarray = (set*)malloc(sizeof(set) * number_of_sets);
```

you are multiplying such a `size_t` value (the `sizeof` operator gives a `size_t`) by a (signed) `int` variable - hence the warning.

To avoid this, either *explicitly cast* `number_of_sets` to a `size_t`, like this:

```c
setarray = (set*)malloc(sizeof(set) * (size_t)number_of_sets);
```

Or, better, change the type of that argument to a `size_t`:

```c
void initSetArray(set *setarray, size_t number_of_sets, size_t number_of_blocks)
{
    setarray = (set*)malloc(sizeof(set) * number_of_sets);
}
```

Generally, when using variables that represent the 'count' or 'size' of objects, an *unsigned* int is prefereable (unless you can *really* have a negative count or size).

Answer (score 1):

The warning is produced under very strict warning settings because the value `number_of_sets` is converted implicitly from `int` to the unsigned type `unsigned long int`, which may have a counter-intuitive value for negative values of `number_of_sets`.

To silence this warning, you can either:

- change the prototype of `initSetArray` to fix the type of the arguments: `number_of_sets` and `numer_of_blocks` should probably be unsigned values with type `size_t` anyway:

  ```
  void initSetArray(set *setarray, size_t number_of_sets, size_t number_of_blocks)
  ```
- alternately, you can add an explicit conversion using the cast operator:

  ```
  void initSetArray(set *setarray, int number_of_sets, int number_of_blocks) {
      setarray = (set*)malloc(sizeof(set) * (size_t)number_of_sets);
  }
  ```

Note however that setting the value of argument `setarray` has no effect on the caller's variable that is used as an argument to `initSetArray`. You should either return the pointer or take a pointer to a pointer argument.