# conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result

Tags: c

```
bool add_player(struct player list[], int* size, const struct player player) {
    char **new_name = (char**)malloc((*size+1) * sizeof(char*));
    int* new_score = malloc((*size+1) * sizeof(int));

    free(new_name);
    free(new_score);
```

What i need change in my code, if i have this error: conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result

Comment: What do you mean `size = int(size)`?  The error suggests that `size` might be `int` (_e.g._ `int size;`) -- is that what you mean?  You're using it as if it's a pointer, but it's not.  If you want more specific help you should show more code than than the line that produces the error.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get rid of the following sign-conversion warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121821/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-following-sign-conversion-warning)

Comment: Марина, what would you like `add_player()` to do when `*size < 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` accepts `size_t` which is an unsigned type. You are taking a signed `int` as the size parameter. Of course, you are likely not using the negative space of such a variable, but when you pass it to malloc, it is being implicitly converted into an unsigned type, and therefore, there is the possibility of flipping negative values (though, I would say that "changing the sign of the result" is misleading, unless you are actually on a system that isn't using two's complement).

Depending on your compiler and settings, you may or may not get a warning.

The solution is to either accept an unsigned type to begin with or perform an explicit typecast to `size_t` to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing. `(size_t)(*size+1)`